# How to create a "scrolling-sliding" transition between two child controllers

Tags: ios, transition, uicontainerview

I am trying to slide between two child controllers that get loaded into a container view. I have found out about the sliding effect in CATransition. However, it doesn't slide the way I want it to. If I am sliding from right to left, I want the current controller to also slide to the left. So, it basically creates a scrolling effect using sliding. How can I achieve that? Here is my current code.

```
    var transition = CATransition();
    transition.duration = 0.25;
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut);
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    if source.prevItem > source.pageControl.currentPage {
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
    } else {
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
    }
    dest.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

    source.transitionFromViewController(
        source.currentChildController!,
        toViewController: dest,
        duration: 0.5,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
        animations: nil,
        completion: { finished in
            source.currentChildController?.removeFromParentViewController()
            dest.didMoveToParentViewController(source)
            source.currentChildController = dest
        }
    );
```

This implementation only brings the destination controller over the current controller even though the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransition_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/kCATransitionPush) for Push transition states: "The layer’s content pushes any existing content as it slides into place. The “Common Transition Subtypes” are used with this transition."